# scala error when extending java.util.Stack : error while loading vector$

Tags: scala

I'm using scala v2.10.2; eclipse with scala plugin v3.0.1; The full error message is:

> error while loading Vector$1, class file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Vector$1.class)' is broken (class
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException/key not found: E)

It occurs when attempting to extending java.util.Stack

```
import java.util.Stack
class MyStack[T] extends Stack[T]{}
```

It's worth noting that java.util.Stack is a subclass of java.util.Vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Stack` extends the essentially deprecated `java.util.Vector`, and thus is also essentially deprecated (they're not *actually* deprecated, but the docs always recommends using newer alternatives if you're running a newer version of Java). The [javadoc for `Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) recommends using the [`java.util.Deque` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example: `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`

Using the `Deque` interface and [`java.util.ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) will probably solve your problem since—referring to pretzels1337's answer—this seems to be a `Vector`-specific bug.

Answer (score 2):

eThis same issue may be part of a larger bug report:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7455

The report claims fixed in Scala 2.10.3-RC1, Scala 2.11.0-M6

I'm waiting for the next stable scala IDE update before verifying fixed (lazy I know) but a simple work around in the mean time is to simply change the class definitions to extend scala.collection.mutable.Stack instead.

--
Most people running into this issue are trying to use swing; for you I can only recommend trying one of the fixed builds of scala.